# Multiple radio button created dynamically inserted in sql

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Programmers, the annoying guy is here to annoy you again so my today problem is I have this HTML form which is used to insert Radio buttons in SQL

```
<?php $q=mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM students");
                while ($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)):
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?=$r['students_id']?></td>
                <td><?=$r['students_name']?></td>
                <td><?=$r['fname']?></td>
                <td><?=$r['students_reg']?></td>
                <td><?=$r['gender']?></td>
                <td>
                    <form action="" method="POST" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="attendance[<?=$r['students_id']?>]" value="Present" required>
                                    Present     
                            </label>
                            <label for="">
                            <input type="radio" name="attendance[<?=$r['students_id']?>]" value="Absent">
                                    Absent
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <?php endwhile ?>
    </table>    
    <button class="btn btn-success form-control"  name="add_attendance">Register</button>
```

**the out i get is this:-**
[image]

my question is how i inserted all selected radio buttons which is created dynamically can be insert there values parallel to thier id's in db sql?

```
if(isset($_POST['check_list'])){
  $selected = implode(",", $_POST['check_list']);
  $q=mysqli_query($dbc,"UPDATE students SET attendance='$selected'");
  if ($q) {
    # code...
    $msg="Data Has Been Saved";
    $sts="success";
  }
  else{
    #code...
    $msg=mysqli_error($dbc);
    $sts="danger";
  }
}
```

I update my code now i only get either present or absent in all fields my want is when i submit one time the present and absent store parallel to the ids

Comment: var_dump $att.. it will be an array

Comment: i cant get it what you said will you please explain thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`attendance` is array input variable so it returning `Array`

You should use for loop to insert / update values,

For example,

```
$att= $_POST['attendance'];
$student_id = $_POST['students_id'];
for($i = 0; $i < count($student_id); $i++)
{
  $q=mysqli_query($dbc,"UPDATE students SET attendance='$att[$i]' WHERE students_id=$student_id[$i]");

}
```

Comment: i tried your code but its do not insert anything in sql db